# Listening to HTTP headers in XUL applications

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xul, xulrunner

Is it possible for example to create an iframe with www page inside and print all the HTTP requests in kind of text element like label or something (it doesn't metter in which one, I just want to preview the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `observerService` to listen to `http-on-modify-request` (request headers) and/or `http-on-examine-response` (response headers).

I don't have complete code at the moment, but see [these snippets](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=2999353&sid=ee27674ab94ab4f5d56680f4f88d7f73#p2999353) to get the idea.